# How to install Xdebug for XAMPP PHP, not macOS PHP?

Tags: php, macos, xampp, homebrew, xdebug

I installed Xdebug using homebrew for my system's PHP and it went fine.

[image]

But I'm trying to debug in my IDE, PhpStorm, which is using XAMPP as the server. It's a different PHP installation (I'm pretty sure!?)

[image]

I say this because obviously, it's missing the "xdebug.." and "Zend OPache.." stuff in the version command. I'm running that version command from PhpStorm's run command tool, BTW.

Lastly, I *super* know it's not installed due to this blinding reminder that I'm absolutely, beyond any possible shadow of a doubt, lost in the sauce.

[image]

I think it's about time I learn how to use the ol' terminal.

Any tips on how to use homebrew to install Xdebug on XAMPP's PHP?

Comment: Why did you install XDebug manually? Isn't is part of XAMPP already?

Comment: @NicoHaase It being installed already would be news to me, as no debugger functions work and the IDE says no debugger is installed. This is a good point to research, however. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to enable it in the php.ini?

Comment: @NicoHaase Was the first thing I did. I will try to find website where I can pay someone to walk me through it and then post solution when I find it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I modified XAMPP's php.ini file to point to the xdebug.so that homebrew installed,
`zend_extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.3/pecl/20220829/xdebug.so"`

Then, I restarted the XAMPP server and ran this in terminal
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php -v`

Before the expected PHP info, there were some errors. Several times in the warnings it stated "...`(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')`..."
Oops.. I swore I chose x86_64..

So, I ran the following in terminal:
`pecl uninstall xdebug`

Then,
`arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug`

Following that I again ran `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php -v` and, voila!

```
PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec 29 2022 08:42:31) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

Xdebug installed :] Works in my IDE too.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew has to be used in a consistent way: you can't use it to install an extension to a program installed by another way. If XAMPP is using its own set of paths and stuff, Homebrew can difficulty adapt to it: it's not made for that situation.

Why don't you change your "PHP executable" and "Configuration file" options to  the homebrew ones?

Comment: I'll look into how to change these file options into the homebrew ones. I must admit though, I don't know what that means. Regardless, if I find a solution this problem I'll update the post with whatever steps I took.